# NA == 1 check returns NA

Tags: r, logical-operators, na

Could someone explain me why:

```
NA == 1 #NA #expect FALSE
NA == NA #NA #expect TRUE
1 == NA #NA #expect FALSE
NA == TRUE #NA #expect FALSE
```

A live example of the usage is `df[df$SomeAttribute == 1,]` where some of `df$SomeAttribute` have `NA` values.

I know one can use `which(df$SomeAttribute == 1)` just question the sanity of logic operations on `NA`.

Comment: The logical operation with NA returns NA.  Use `is.na`

Comment: If a value is unknown and thus could be anything, the comparison is also unknown and could be anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NA` simply means that a value is missing/unknown. Therefore `NA == 1` yields `NA`. The outcome of the comparison with `==` is unknown, since we don't know if the missing value is `1` or something else.

The same reasoning can be applied to the other tests, which is why they all return `NA`.

---

As pointed out by @akrun in a comment, the proper way to check whether a value `x` is missing is to use the function `is.na(x)`. A comparison of the type `x == NA` would not give the desired result.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that R applies more strict logic condition, i.e. the unknown might be not the known value, if it isn't proved otherwise, therefore NA not equal 1 (yielding FALSE).